# Как сделать так, чтобы видео в VLC проигрывателе ВСЕГДА открывались на скорости 2х?

Tags: vlc

Нужно задать по умолчанию что бы проигрыватель открывал видео, так как имеется больше сотни видео, а не хочется тратить время на переключение скорости каждый раз (то есть больше сотни раз) воспроизведения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools -> Preferences -> Выбрать в самом низу слева Show Settings - All  -> Input/Codecs -> чуток прокрутить вниз -> Playback Control  - Playback Speed

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за ответ